# Convert vertical array data to horizontal array data

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk

I have a file with 25 matrices in a file, and each matrix is has 128 rows and 5 columns. Each matrix are putted one after the other, in a vertical way. Like this

File input(file1):

```
Array1
Array2
Array3
...
Array25
```

I want to put each array in a horizontal way. Like this(file2)

```
Array1  Array2  Array3 ... Array25
```

I tried to use this command :

```
pr -25t -w 4000 file1 > file2
```

But is not working as I want.

Comment: Could you clarify your "Array" examples?  What you show is just strings.  The actual input/output you *show* could be handled with `tr '\n' ' ' <file1 >file2` but I don't think that's what you want.  (Or is it?)

Comment: A KISS approach might be to split into 25 individual files e.g. `split -l128 file1` and then re-assemble them using `paste` e.g (assuming the default split prefix, and brace expansion) `paste xa{a..y} > file2`

Comment: @steeldriver, it works!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider this test file with arrays with 3 rows each:

```
$ cat File
1 2
3 4
5 6
a b
c d
e f
A B
C D
E F
```

Now, let's concatenate the arrays:

```
$ awk -v nr=3 '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) {for (j=i;j<=NR;j+=nr) printf "%s ",a[j]; print""}}' File
1 2 a b A B 
3 4 c d C D 
5 6 e f E F
```

In your data file, there are 128 rows per array.  In that case, run:

```
awk -v nr=128 '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) {for (j=i;j<=NR;j+=nr) printf "%s ",a[j]; print""}}' File
```

#### How it works

- `-v nr=128`

  This sets the variable `nr` to the number of rows per array.
- `a[NR]=$0`

  `NR` is the line number.  We save each row (line) in the array `a`.
- `END{for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) {for (j=i;j<=NR;j+=nr) printf "%s ",a[j]; print""}}`

  After we have read in all the rows, this writes them out again in the form that you want.

  To do this, we loop over the variable `i` starting with `i=1` and finishing with `i=nr`.  For each `i`, we print the new row `i`.  For each `i` value, we loop over `j` where `j` is the number of row of the old file that belongs on row `i` of the new file`.

#### Variation

Although it makes it more difficult for a beginner to read, a ternary statement can be used to give a slight improvement in the formatting:

```
$ awk -v nr=3 '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) for (j=i;j<=NR;j+=nr) printf "%s%s",a[j],(j+nr<=NR?" ":"\n")}' File
1 2 a b A B 11 22
3 4 c d C D 33 44
5 6 e f E F 55 66
```

`j+nr<=NR?" ":"\n"` is a *ternary statement*.  It returns a space if `j+nr<=NR`.  Otherwise, it returns a newline.